# RNFS.exists() always returns TRUE

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I am using react-native-fs and for some reason whenever I use the exists() method it is always returning as TRUE. A sample of my code looks like this:

```js
let path_name = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/userdata/settings.json";

if (RNFS.exists(path_name)){
    console.log("FILE EXISTS")
    file = await RNFS.readFile(path_name)
    console.log(file)
    console.log("DONE")
}
else {
    console.log("FILE DOES NOT EXIST")
}
```

The output at the console is "FILE EXISTS", then an error is thrown that says:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   /data/data/com.test7/files/userdata/settings.json'

How can it exist using the `exists` method, but not the `readFile` method?

On further checking it seems that RNFS.exists() is always returning true, no matter what the filename is. Why is it always returning true?

A display of path_name says `/data/data/com.test7/files/userdata/settings.json`.

Even if I change my code to something nonsensical like the following code:

```js
if (RNFS.exists("blah")){
    console.log("BLAH EXISTS");
} else {
    console.log("BLAH DOES NOT EXIST");
}
```

It still evaluates to true and displays the message:

```js
BLAH EXISTS
```

I have displayed the contents of the directory and verified these files do not exist.

Comment: try `console.log` on `path_name`, from error log it looks like not correct

Comment: @Val Interesting, it says `/data/data/com.test7/files/userdata/settings.json`. Not sure why it has /data twice or if that's what it should be.

Comment: @Val Also, I originally had `undefined` in my error message, though I think that was from a misspelling of DocumentDirectoryPath in my test case. That is fixed now and I have adjusted my question accordingly.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That's because [`RNFS.exists()`](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#existsfilepath-string-promiseboolean) returns a `Promise`. Put a `Promise` object in a test of `if statement` will always be true.

Do this instead:

```js
if (await RNFS.exists("blah")){
    console.log("BLAH EXISTS");
} else {
    console.log("BLAH DOES NOT EXIST");
}
```

Or:

```js
RNFS.exists("blah")
    .then( (exists) => {
        if (exists) {
            console.log("BLAH EXISTS");
        } else {
            console.log("BLAH DOES NOT EXIST");
        }
    });
```